# best way in javascript to make console.log calls not cause problems when there's no console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, firebug

I'm using firebug and making lots of console.log, .info, .dir calls, etc. When the app runs on a machine with firebug turned off, it can cause errors. What's the best technique to avoid that? This seems to work:

```
// global scope
if (typeof(console) == 'undefined') {
    console = {
        info : function() {},
        dir : function() {},
        error : function() {},
        log : function() {}
    };
}
```

but I don't like the idea of manually maintaining a list of console functions. Other ideas?

(We've also got jQuery on the project if that helps.)

Comment: Personally I think the solution you have above is best.  The fact is, if you don't want unknown objects or functions causing errors, you have to either remove them or define them in a non-invasive manner as you have above.

Comment: Do you use a compiler like Google's or Yahoo's to compress and verify your JavaScript? I've been looking for something that removes all `console` commands at compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally just use [`$.noop`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/core.js#L563) to shorten it like this:

```
if(!window.console)
  window.console = { log: $.noop, group: $.noop, groupEnd: $.noop };
```

But whatever functions you're using, add them in.

Comment: Nice, I didn't now about $.noop

Comment: @Marcel - It's not, you're referencing the *same* empty function, not creating a new one each time.